# Java: Linking user inputs to constructor and back

Tags: java, default-constructor

Having a real issue finding a "user-input" line of code that will allow for 2 programs, one being a constructor, to communicate with each other. I'm looking to have a user input his/her value, have that value go over to the constructor, and return it back to the original program with whatever modifications. Thanks in advance!

```
  //condensed...

  Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Please enter a year between 2001 - 2025: ");
  date = input.nextInt();

  while(date < DATE_START || date > DATE_STOP)
  {
     System.out.println("You entered an incorrect value.");
     System.out.println("You entered " + date);
     System.out.print("Please enter a year between 2001 - 2025: ");
     date = input.nextInt();
  }
     System.out.println("The number associate with this delivery is: " + ?????);
```

I can't find out how to access the associated program, looking for the user to enter in values in this program, and for the other program to return it for display

```
//Other program condensed...
public class Delivery
{
 private int year;
 private int number;
 private int code;
 private double weight;
 private double fee;

 public int getYear()
  {
     return year;
  }
  public void setYear(int yr)
  {
     year = yr;
  }

...//condensed 
   public Delivery()
{

  year = ????
  number = 
  code = 
  weight = 
  fee = 
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you need to create a Delivery Object with the user input for the date? If so, you'd have to add a constructor to Delivery. I.E. public Delivery(int inputYear){year=inputYear;} and create it by doing Delivery dev = new Delivery(date) where date is the user input.

Comment: "2 programs, one being a constructor" -- I'm afraid I don't understand what you're trying to say here. In Java, a `constructor` is the method that is used to initialize a new object when it is created; it doesn't return anything except by setting values in that object. I'm also not sure what you mean by "program" -- class?

Comment: keshlam, do you see how to link the two together? I'm obviously not a seasoned developer, but am a student. Can you assist me in making this work? Thanks

Comment: @user3304613 Please accept the best answer by clicking on the `(tick symbol)`. It will help people with similar issues to select their answer with ease next time. `Upvoting` and `accepting` an answer motivates people to answer more.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to add a constructor with a parameter and then have a method that returns the value in the form that you need.

For instance you could have:

```
class Delivery {
    private int year;
    public Delivery(String date) {
        year = Integer.parseInt(date);
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }
}
```

then in your other part of the program you can:

```
Delivery delivery = new Delivery(date);
int year = delivery.getYear();
```

Well, something like that anyway...

Answer (score 1):

Simple answer which is general across Java. code can be even simpler. steps below.

1. Pass your value to the constructor from you program.
2. The constructor sets the value of the instance variable in your class
3. For that instance variable write a getter method (similar to one in a pojo)
4. After a call to the constructor call the getter method which will return the value set.